# Sobre distintas interpretaciones del ciclo for

Tags: java, lista, loops, ciclos

Como se lee el ciclo for del código? Supongo que se lee así: Para cada digito de tipo `char` leelo y convertirlo a un arreglo de caracteres o tal vez asi: Para cada digito de tipo `char` leelo y agregalo a un arreglo de caracteres?

```
 System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos para la sucesion1");
for (char digito : q.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
    seq1.add(digito - '0');
}
```

En general, después de los 2 puntos `:` puede ir cualquier acción/condición que tenga que hacer el ciclo `for`? o existen restricciones para esta forma distinta de representar el ciclo `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Estructura de un ciclo `for(){}` en java:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En codigo:**

```
for(inicialización;condicion;incremento)
{
    //instrucciones
}
```

**1)**

> La ejecución de la estructura de control for comienza con la
>   instrucción de **inicialización**. Esta instrucción suele realizar la
>   inicialización de una variable de control que suele conocerse como
>   **centinela**.

**2)**

> A continuación se comprueba la **condición** cuyo resultado tiene que ser
>   un valor booleano true o false.

**3)**

> Si la condición se evalúa como true se ejecuta el bloque de
>   instrucciones delimitadas por las llaves que solo son necesarias si
>   hay más de una instrucción.

**4)**

> Después se ejecuta la instrucción de incremento y vuelve a comprobarse
>   la condición. Así sucesivamente hasta que la condición no se cumple.

**En tu caso:**

---

Pedimos un digito.

```
System.out.println("Introduzca los digitos para la sucesion1");
```

---

Preparamos un for para recorrer x dato:

```
for(char digito:){
}
```

---

En nuestro caso al hacer for(char: digito) vamos a leer cada caracter que componga al string que se guarde en digito.

---

Allí interviene `:` estos dos puntos indican cual sera el valor de
la inicialización (recordemos la forma de un for).

```
for(char digito: q.nextLine()){
}
```

---

`q` sera nuestro scanner del dato y `nextLine()` retornara todo el string leido hasta la siguiente linea, es decir:

"Hola soy pepe" se guardara completo, a diferencia de usar `next()` que solo
Guarda hasta el espacio "Hola soy pepe" -> "Hola".

---

Seguimos, ahora ese string guardado le aplicaremos `toCharArray()`, esta funcion convierte ese string en un array de caracteres.

```
for(char digito: q.nextLine().toCharArray()){
}
```

---

**Entonces estamos diciendo:** *"Para cada carácter contenido en el scanner de `nextline()`, haga lo que esta entre las dos llaves."*

---

**¿Como hace el for para funcionar sin tener incrementador o condicional?:** En el ciclo for, la inicialización, la condición y el incremento son instrucciones opcionales, pero este tiene un inicializador que es un array, lo que obliga al `for` a pasar por cada una de las letras que conforman dicho array.

---

Seguido agregamos a `seq1` el carácter que este en la iteración del for (supongo es un array)

```
for (char digito : q.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
    seq1.add(digito - '0');
}
```

---

**Traduciendo todo el for:** *Para cada caracter del array de caracteres obtenido del scanner que pidio el digito al usuario, agreguelo al array `seq1`*

---

**Ahora bien, para tu pregunta:**

Si y no, luego de la inicializacion puedes agregar cualquier "condicion", tomando en cuenta que debes usar operadores logicos como `&&(and)` y `||(or)` y respetando la estructura basica:

```
for(inicializacion ; aqui || tus && condiciones ; contador){}
```

En cuanto a las acciones irán en el bloque de código no en el cuerpo del `for`, es decir:

```
for(int i=0; i<a || i<b || i>c; i++){
    // AQUI 
    int x = i + 100;
    int z = i x 2;
}
```

Ejemplos:

```
for (int i = 1, j = 100; i <= 100 && j > 0; i = i - 1 , j = j-1) {
    System.out.println("Inside For Loop");
}

for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 || otraCondicion() ; i++ ) {
  System.out.printLn("Inside another For Loop");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, lo que se quiere decir en ese for es:

```
//  Para cada char en el siguiente array de chars.
for (char digito : q.nextLine().toCharArray()) {  
    seq1.add(digito - '0');  //  has lo siguiente.
}
```

Tu variable **digito** representa cada char dentro del array que devuelve **q.nextLine().toCharArray()**, tomando uno a uno de ellos hasta que recorra todo el conjunto.

Answer (score 1):

El bucle for que escribes es una implementación especial del bucle for incluída en Java 5, llamada [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

En alto nivel, la sintaxis significa:

> Para cada variable de tipo `char`, a la que llamaremos `digito`, que esté incluída en el array resultante de convertir un `String` a array de `char`:
>    (Logica del bucle)

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
//un array cualquiera
int[] listaDeNumeros = {1, 2, 3, 4};   

System.out.println("For-each");
for (int numero : listaDeNumeros) {
    System.out.println("Numero: " + numero);
}

System.out.println("For tradicional");
for (int i = 0; i < listaDeNumeros.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Numero: " + listaDeNumeros[i]);
}
```

El resultado es:

```
For-each
Numero: 1
Numero: 2
Numero: 3
Numero: 4
For tradicional
Numero: 1
Numero: 2
Numero: 3
Numero: 4
```

Si quieres saber cómo funciona en mayor profundidad, te recomiendo [esta pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work). A modo de resumen, antes de Java 5 la implementación de **for-each** se hacía así:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterador = listaDeNumeros.iterator();
int numero;
while(iterador.hasNext())  {
    numero = iterador.next();
}
```

Tienes la ventaja de que la referencia a cada item de tu colección está ya creada, pero pierdes la variable de control del bucle **for** tradicional.

Incidentalmente, el bucle foreach puede usarse con cualquier objeto que implemente la interfaz [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), por ejemplo, todos los objetos que están en el framework de java [`java.util.Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html).

Comment: creo que le falta un casting en `numero=iterator.next();`, deberia de ser `numero=(Integer) iterator.next();` o bien `numero=(int) iterator.next();`. no?

Comment: o tal vez ya no hace falta el casting porque ya le indicaste que solo va a recibir `<Interger>` en la declaracion de `iterator`

Comment: Muy buena respuesta por cierto :) gracias!

Comment: @Michelle Exacto, el Iterator ya recibe el tipo necesario en su declaración. ¡Muchas gracias!